# JavaScript equivalent of this jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following jQuery code:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    animated: 'fade',
    placement: 'bottom',
    html: true
});
```

How to do the same without jQuery?

Comment: Show me a jsfiddle of what happens

Comment: This appears to be a tooltip plugin dependent on jquery. So, you may need to load jquery rather than pure js

Comment: @Asperger here it is http://jsfiddle.net/joshvito/v4p24ak8/1/

Comment: @JulianDavidBautistaOsorio https://jsfiddle.net/v3ycehnd/

Comment: Just for a first glimpse

Comment: wow, that's pretty good :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me tell you that this is not ideal Javascript code but I kept it this way on purpose so that you can clearly see the steps involved.

I could create a perfect a equivalent but I will let you play around now : )

**PS:** Little mission for you. Try to add a second parameter that lets you choose the direction of the tooltip in relation to the target.

Here the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v3ycehnd/2/

```
var elem = document.getElementById("sample");
var tooltip = document.getElementsByClassName("tooltip");

function showToolTip(target) {
  target.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    tooltip[0].style.top = this.getBoundingClientRect().bottom + "px";
    tooltip[0].style.opacity = 1;
    tooltip[0].style.transform = "scale(1)";
  });

  target.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(){
    tooltip[0].style.opacity = 0;
    tooltip[0].style.transform = "scale(0)";
  });
}

showToolTip(elem)
```

If you want it get html and place it into the tooltip then you can do so with `innerHTML` (I hate it it).

If you want to get the content from another page and paste it onto your tooltip you can do so with `AJAX`.